# Form not showing due to routing problem in action parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, maatwebsite-excel

I am working on an Excel import module as part of a CRM for my company. I want to import an excel sheet. I use the Maatwebsite Excel package, version 3.1. I want to show the form and then upload a sheet. However I can't even get to that point. I have already determined the issue is within the form route, just not sure what it is exactly that I am missing.

Routes that I use to display the page (index works fine)
[image]

Form used to get the Excel sheet imported
[image]

Navigation bar link in the menu
[image]

DataController (from which I am trying to call the import method)
[image]

If you know what may be wrong please do tell, this is really frustrating!

Route code:

```php
Route::get('importeren', 'Datacontroller@index');

Route::post('import', 'Datacontroller@import');
```

```php
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form action="import" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="import_file">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Import">
    </form>
</div>
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Imports\DataImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DataController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('importeren');
    }

    public function import(Request $request){

        Excel::import(new DataImport(), $request->file('import_file'));

         return redirect()->route('/home');
    }
}
```

Comment: `route()` helper is for named routes

Comment: So I can just do:

<form action="import" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

And it will work?

Thinking: Do I have to specify? So like: action="DataController@import"

Comment: Give a name to your route. You are using the `route()` helper in your form action, but your route have not name. Sorry, but since the code is in a image, I cant't copy paste to show you.

Comment: I can paste it for you, one second

Answer (score 0):

Don't use route() method because you're not defining any routes name, use something like:
          form action="/import" method="POST" enctype="multipart/formdata">

Comment: Or better yet, name the route

Answer (score 0):

You can [give a name to your route](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes):

```
Route::post('import', 'Datacontroller@import')->name('import');
```

and leave the form action as it is with the [route() helper](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-route):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form action="{{ route('import') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="import_file">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Import">
    </form>
</div>
```

You could also use the [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-url) helper and leave the route with no name, but I highly recommend the option of giving your route a name.

```
<form action="{{ url('import') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Note that in the controller return you are also using a [redirect to a named route](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes), so I suggest that you give that route a name and use that name in the redirect. For example:

```
Route::get('home', 'SomeController@someMethod')->name('home');
```

and

```
return redirect()->route('home');
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use route() only with route name, use this instead :
`return redirect('/home');`